# how to take the length to know the amount of numbers that were generated?

Tags: javascript, math

```
var a;
        do{
        a = Math.round(Math.random() *100);
       console.log(a);

       if(a === 6){
           console.log("Chegou no "+ a)
       }

        }while(a !== 6);
```

//  how to take the length to know the amount of numbers that were generated ?

Comment: Use a counter variable and increment it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a;
  let counter = 0;
  do{
  a = Math.round(Math.random() *100);
  console.log(a);
  counter ++; 

  if(a === 6){
    console.log("Chegou no "+ a)
    }

  } while(a !== 6);
  console.log(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a counter.

```js
let a;
let counter = 0;

do {
    a = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log(a);
    counter++;

    if(a === 6) console.log("Chegou no "+ a)
} while (a !== 6)
```